# How to enable scroll buttons for tabcontrol in powershell GUI

Tags: winforms, powershell, user-interface

I am struggling as I am unable to find a command that would add Scroll buttons for my powershell Script. I have multiple tabs within scripts. Now I have more tabs than can fit in script window. How to enable Scroll buttons that I could switch between the powershell gui tabs?

Sorry for not adding the script.

```
################ Forms ########################

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(505,570)
$form.text = "Integrated"


################ Tabs ########################
$tabcontrols = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
$tabcontrols.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(605,570)

$form.Controls.Add($tabcontrols)

$tabMailboxScript = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$tabMailboxScript.Text = "Mailbox details"
$tabcontrols.Controls.Add($tabMailboxScript)

$tabCFGOwnerScript = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$tabCFGOwnerScript.Text = "CFG Owner"
$tabcontrols.Controls.Add($tabCFGOwnerScript)

$tabGetACLScript = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$tabGetACLScript.Text = "Get-ACL"
$tabcontrols.Controls.Add($tabGetACLScript)

$tabCFGFolderScript = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$tabCFGFolderScript.Text = "CFG Folder"
$tabcontrols.Controls.Add($tabCFGFolderScript)
```

Comment: Can you add your code for how your are setting up your tabs? [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell by looking at the [class's MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx), changing the tabs to a scrolling selection doesn't appear to be supported. You can set it to allow multiple rows of tabs, or you should be able to hide the tab selector and setup your own buttons to scroll between tabs, and then just display a label or something to show what the current tab is.